# Best setting Reledpar, Reledmac

Tags: eledmac, parallel, eledpar

this is my first use of Latex (MiKTeX distribution). Should I set a book poetry with parallel text in dialect and left translation on the right. There will be many footnotes. I am very happy the first result. I need to better set the following things, and I ask your help:

1. I would like that the text starts without the pages == and without blank pages between a poem and another.    If I use `\nopgb` nothing occurs
2. for the title if I use `newverse` / `poemtitlev the title is in the center and I can not put it flush left with the text also numbering starts from the title. Instead as put now with presentness, the numbering is correct, alignment as well, but the title of the poems does not flow in the Index.
3. I can not place the center of the page only the text of the left-hand pages, but always with the verses all lined up on the left!
4. I can not change the font of the poetic text only present on the left-hand pages
   (The notes font is fine with me) and I can not even standardize the same font of the sidenote to that of the footnote.
5. Finally If I compile with pdflatex (the PDF is produced right) I obtain many error for each verse:

   > ```
   > "Missing number, treated as zero.
   > A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
   > (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
   > look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
   > Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)"
   > ```

Thanks a lot in advance to all of you and congratulations!

This is my settings:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\usepackage[series={A,B,D},noledgroup]{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{normal}
\Xarrangement[B]{twocol}
\Xarrangement[D]{paragraph}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}
%\maxchunks{9999}

\sidenotemargin{left}
\renewcommand{\ledlsnotefontsetup}{\tiny\it}% left  (small)
\renewcommand{\ledrsnotefontsetup}{\tiny\it}% right   (small)
\leftnoteupfalse
\rightnoteupfalse
\setsidenotesep{ $|$ }
\Xlemmadisablefontselection [A,B,D]
\Xlemmafont{\bfseries}
\Xcolalign[]{} 
\setgoalfraction{0.98}
\Xmaxhnotes{0.25\textheight}

% Additional Options

\begin{document}
    \large

    \begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
           \beginnumbering
              \noindent
              \firstlinenum{2}
               \linenumincrement{4}
                      \begin{astanza}[{\textbf{U giud}}] 
  % \renewcommand{\poemtoc}{section}
   %\newverse[\poemtitle{U giudizia finale}]                
%\setline{1}
Cumm sem brav a parlà!&     
E quant cattiv  a tretechià!&               
Sfuggiam i dote, i meglia&  
Sfuggiam i dote, i meglia& 
Sfuggiam i dote, i meglia& 
Sfuggiam i dote, i meglia& 
Sfuggiam i dote, i meglia& 
Sfuggiam i dote, i meglia& 
so’ quillia de nu \edtext{‘rrafacan}{\Afootnote{Uno che arraffa qualsiasi cosa.}}&  
ma se i man i mitt semp tu&     
‘ndu taschin ca si \edtext{scialone}{\Afootnote{Chi si dà allo sperpero, allo spreco.}}&        
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
embè,  ti affianka u  \edtext{cutecone}{\Afootnote{Il contrario di scialone, uno che non spende neanche un centesimo.}}&    
Quella coteke da \edtext{purcare}{\Afootnote{Chi alleva ed accudisce i porci. In senso figurato persona sudicia moralmente.}}!&
%\ledrightnote{10-R}        
Ah! Ca sa’ sbatt ‘mbaccia u mur&    
a tè’ toste sul u \edtext{zaqquare}{\Afootnote{Persona sporca, sudicia anche moralmente, con accostamento al pecoraio o al capraio, nel dialetto barese è il derivato di giaguaro per indicare chi veste in modo appariscente, con bigiotterie ed andatura gongolante. Il termine è di probabile origine punica, originario di Saqqara a finir}}.&
%\ledlefttnote{12-R}        
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
\edtext{mene bucia  a lontre e  vask}{\lemma{mene \dots\ vask}\Afootnote{Modo di dire di chi salta da una verità all'altra tramite argomentazioni sillogistiche}}.&
iss jè  tutt e nesciun, u fess!&        
putete chiamà u \edtext{‘cciaccafrask}{\Afootnote{Una persona piena di vanità e capricci; termine derivato dal linguaggio contadino indicante l'addetto a comprimere le cataste di frasche durante le puliture dei campi, dei confini, delle piante infestanti.}}. &
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
fa’ i lutemia u \edtext{scampaverd}{\Afootnote{Chi riesce a cavarsela nelle situazioni in cui è richiesto impegno, sacrificio senza effettivamente farlo.}}!&
Ne iè ‘ppusate e i séns sporke?&
Ne v’azzeccate u \edtext{scampaforke}{\Afootnote{Pseudopredicatore al meno truffatore, che intrigando spinge il popolo alla rivolta e riesce sempre a scampare alle forche.}}!& 
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
si sul nu \edtext{vottagliomber}{\Afootnote{L'aggettivo si richiama alla fatica del mito di Sisifo scaltro ed astuto tra i mortali. Come punizione per la sagacia dell'uomo che aveva osato sfidare gli dèi, Zeus decise che avrebbe dovuto spingere un masso dalla base alla cima di un monte. Tuttavia, ogni volta che raggiungeva la cima, il masso rotolava alla base e così per l'eternità Sisifo avrebbe dovuto ricominciare da capo la sua scalata senza mai riuscirci.}}.&
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
allore si  nu \edtext{sarchiapone}{\Afootnote{Chi dovrebbe svolgere il durissimo lavoro della sarchiatura del terreno: sarchiatore se è faticatore mentre sarchiapone se non affronta nemmeno la sfida.}}.& 
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
si cumm nu \edtext{sciusciamemmokke}{\Afootnote{Uno che non riesce a far nulla nemmeno con la grazia di un divino soffio vitale in bocca.}},&   
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
paia aier, ogge, ancor e chiù&      
\edtext{smiveze}{\Afootnote{Smilzo, scarso, esile, inconsistente.}} e \edtext{mammalucc}{\Afootnote{I Mamelucchi furono soldati delle milizie turche e circasse, di origine servile al servizio dei califfi abbasidi ed impiegati nell'amministrazione e nell'esercito. Chiamati ghilmān in età abbaside, con il califfo al-Mu'tasim essi furono addestrati all'uso delle armi e, successivamente, furono usati da tutte le dinastie nate dopo la disintegrazione del potere califfale. Per estens. sciocco, stupido.}}&
o u musse storcia u \edtext{rrangiaporcia}{\Afootnote{Uno che è abituato ad acciarpare, privo di abilità e capacità secondo i propri porci comodi}}.&
Scart \edtext{acciavomere}{\Afootnote{Termine che definirebbe la parte ad alta curvatura del vomere, l'àccia [dal fr. hache] significa accetta  con testa forgiata in metallo e manico di legno ed è una variante di azza. Il nome “vomero” deriva dal "gioco del vomere" che i contadini della collina del Vomero a Napoli, praticavano nei giorni festivi, sfidandosi a tracciare con l'aratro il solco più diritto; questa usanza vi ha così lasciato il nome.}} ratta pil& 
de \edtext{scarciamort}{\Afootnote{Il termine compare nel testo medioevale “I Reali di Francia” (di Andrea da  Barberino del 1491) che tratta delle battaglie ed imprese della generazione degli imperatori, re, duchi, principi, baroni e paladini di Francia da Costantino Imperatore fino a Orlando Conte d'Anglante.  Nel Libro primo, Cap.33, a proposito delle guardie dei Saracini: “L'Agente Saracina tornò a' suoi padiglioni, e dinanzi al Re Anebruno fu portato Tribarco di Scarcia morto...” (era il re di Scarzia). Nell'accezione dialettale nostra lo scarciamorto indica proprio chi dallo status di re, è divenuto morto (di fame e di gloria) per una serie di complotti e congiure fallite.}} e  \edtext{sferrafucile}{\Afootnote{Chi è altamente garoso e che sta sempre all'erta in difesa della proprietà e dei beni, pronto a “sferrare il fucile” in maniera paranoica.}}.&
Recurde cu \edtext{scavezacan}{\Afootnote{Miserabile; persona professionalmente mediocre; Lo scalzacane è uno che va scalzo come un cane}} & 
ze cunfonn cu \edtext{fraccagess}{\Afootnote{Gli addetti alla riduzione in minuzie del gesso. Dal latino frangere rompere, attraverso la forma parlata fragicare. Anticamente nel processo di estrazione e produzione del gesso i blocchi provenienti dalla cava, che si presentano di differenti pezzature, venivano ridotti di dimensioni, per agevolarne il trasporto e poi frantumanti e macinati in  frantoi rudimentali per la successiva fase di cottura ai forni. Il fraccagesso è un seccatore che importuna di continuo, un guastafeste.}} &
e u \edtext{vraccellit}{\Afootnote{Chi riesce ad avere la prelazione su qualsiasi cosa, un beniamino prediletto.}}, mik fess&
chi \edtext{capuzzell}{\Afootnote{Dirigente minore, che esercita un potere limitato ma in modo arrogante}} fa baccan.\&
        [\begin{flushright}\textit{Settembre 2000}\end{flushright}]
    \end{astanza}
            \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    %\setstanzaindents{7,0}
%\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
    \linenummargin{left}
    \firstlinenum{2}
               \linenumincrement{4}
            \begin{astanza}[{\textbf{Il giud}}] 
 %\renewcommand{\poemtoc}{section}
 %\newverse[\poemtitle{Il giudizio finale}]
%\setline{1}
Come siam bravi a parlare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
sono quelli di un arraffacani \ledrightnote{[10]trad.lett. nome composto}.&
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
lui è tutto e nessuno, il fesso,        &
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
Se ha la testa vuoto a perdere  &
fa’ le loquele lo scampaverde!\ledrightnote{[25,27]trad.lett. nome composto}&
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!&     
E quanto cattivi  a criticare!\&        
        \end{astanza}
      \endnumbering
        \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
           \beginnumbering
              \noindent
               \firstlinenum{2}
               \linenumincrement{4}
                      \begin{astanza}[{\textbf{tempe}}] 
  % \renewcommand{\poemtoc}{section}
   %\newverse[\poemtitle{I tempe passat}]                
%\setline{1}
Chiù i m’aggir atturn &
Chiù i m’aggir atturn &
Chiù i m’aggir atturn &
Chiù i m’aggir atturn &
Chiù i m’aggir atturn &
Chiù i m’aggir atturn &
Chiù i m’aggir atturn &
Chiù i m’aggir atturn &
Chiù i m’aggir atturn &
a \edtext{mazz e pivez}{\Afootnote{Gioco da bambini simile al moderno baseball che si teneva usando un bastone ed un piolo appuntito alle estremità. Quest'ultimo una volta sistemato a terra veniva colpito e mandato il più lontano possibile.}}ze iucav&
Chiù i m’aggir atturn &
Chiù i m’aggir atturn &
Chiù i m’aggir atturn &
Chiù i m’aggir atturn &
Chiù i m’aggir atturn &
Chiù i m’aggir atturn &
\edtext{Dindr i case chi pecciun &
ca svulazzen ‘ngopp a trav &
e ‘nda stall pecur e ciuccia}{\lemma{Dindr \dots\ ciuccia}\Afootnote{A partire dalle epoche del brigantaggio fino a quelle delle povertà post-belliche, erano in tanti da avere un posto a casa per gli animali per tre ragioni: per non lasciarli incostuditi in ricoveri esterni lontani dal rischio di razzie, per sfruttarne il calore sopratutto in inverno, per usufruirne dei fetori ed effluvi benefici che proteggevano i conviventi, padroni e familiari, dalle malattie asmatiche e bronchiali.}} &
a matin che cuncert sunav!\&
[\begin{flushright}\textit{poesia del 1990}\end{flushright}]
\end{astanza}
\endnumbering
        \end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
           \beginnumbering
              \noindent
               \firstlinenum{2}
               \linenumincrement{4}
                \begin{astanza}[{\textbf{I tempistori}}] 
  % \renewcommand{\poemtoc}{section}
   %\newverse[\poemtitle{U giudizia finale}]                
%\setline{1}
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno &
Più io mi giro attorno \&
\end{astanza}
\endnumbering
        \end{Rightside}
        \end{pages}
\Pages
\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
           \beginnumbering
              \noindent
               \firstlinenum{2}
               \linenumincrement{4}
                      \begin{astanza}[{\textbf{Ullu}}] 
  % \renewcommand{\poemtoc}{section}
   %\newverse[\poemtitle{I tempe passat}]                
%\setline{1}
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
vRire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
pecchè cacciave sempr nu defett&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
Rire se ‘ngopp i cos ce reflett.&
ma dopp \edtext{accannat}{\Afootnote{Sistemare secondo la canna che è un'antica misura di lunghezza e superficie agraria, con valore compreso tra due e tre metri.}} e misse perbene &
decette: «quissia ne pigliane fok».\&
[\begin{flushright}\textit{2012}\end{flushright}]
\end{astanza}
\endnumbering
        \end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
           \beginnumbering
              \noindent
               \firstlinenum{2}
               \linenumincrement{4}
                \begin{astanza}[{\textbf{Ullo allo}}] 
  % \renewcommand{\poemtoc}{section}
   %\newverse[\poemtitle{U giudizia finale}]                
%\setline{1}
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Ma dai è solo apparenza! Non sembra!&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
si lamentava pure degli amici&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.&
Rido se sulle cose ci rifletto.\&
\end{astanza}
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}


\Pages

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here, partialy answer to your questions (but in the future you should create one question by problem, with a MWE by problem).

1. Just write all your poems in the same `\begin{pages}…\end{pages}\Pages` structure, and use `\setline` to restart line number.
2. I didn't understand what you have tried that does not work. Please provide real MWE
3. I didn't understand you english sentence (I am not an english speaker) and what you expect.
4. Your font on left and right side should be the same, or you will have problem with synchronism. You can change the font of the footnotes with `Xnotenumfont` and `notenumfontX` (§ 7.6.1 of the handbook). You can change marginal font by redefining `\ledlsnotefontsetup` and `\ledrsnotefontsetup`(§12.2.3 of the actual handbook)
5. You have not defined stanza indentation. You must use `\setstanzaindents` and `\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}`. Please read § 9 of  reledmac handbook.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Maïeul! Apologizes for my bad English, I write better in French. Thank at command `\setstanzaindents` and `\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}` I resolve all error messages.

I also solved with the footnote. But it remains a problem: the poems always start from page 2 instead of by 1 which is white! I suspect that my scheme is incorrect. If I use throughout the book only one `\begin{pages}…\end{pages}\Pages` structure, the program compile only the last inserted poetry always starting from the page 2! I insert here the two schemes (MWE) that I tried: what is the correct schema or how to modify them to best settings so I have the beginning from page 1 and each new poem always in new odd page (not to follow one after the other in same page)? Thank's very much I visit all your website and list of publication write with reledmac-reledpar.

First schema:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}
% Additional Options

\begin{document}
        \large
            \begin{pages}
            \begin{Leftside}
                \beginnumbering
                    \setstanzaindents{7,0}
                    \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
               \begin{astanza}[{\textbf{POEM1 dial}}]
verse  verse verse 1!&  
verse verse verse 2!&   
verse verse verse 3!&
verse verse verse 4!&               
verse verse verse 88!\&             
    \end{astanza}
    \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
        \begin{Rightside}
            \beginnumbering
                \setstanzaindents{7,0}
                \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
                \linenummargin{left}
                \begin{astanza}[{\textbf{POEM1 ita}}] 
verse  verse verse 1!&  
verse verse verse 2!&
verse verse verse 3!&
verse verse verse 4!&   
verse verse verse 88!\&         
        \end{astanza}
      \endnumbering
        \end{Rightside}
        \begin{Leftside}
                \beginnumbering
                    \setstanzaindents{7,0}
                    \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
               \begin{astanza}[{\textbf{POEM2 dial}}]
verse  verse verse 1!&  
verse verse verse 2!&   
verse verse verse 3!&
verse verse verse 4!&   
verse verse verse 88!\&     
\end{astanza}
      \endnumbering
        \end{Leftside}
       \begin{Rightside}
            \beginnumbering
                \setstanzaindents{7,0}
                \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
                \linenummargin{left}
                \begin{astanza}[{\textbf{POEM2 ita}}] 
verse  verse verse 1!&  
verse verse verse 2!&   
verse verse verse 3!&
verse verse verse 4!&   
verse verse verse 88!\&     
\end{astanza}
      \endnumbering
        \end{Rightside}
        \begin{Leftside}
                \beginnumbering
                    \setstanzaindents{7,0}
                    \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
               \begin{astanza}[{\textbf{POEM3 dial}}]
verse  verse verse 1!&  
verse verse verse 2!&
verse verse verse 3!&
verse verse verse 4!&   
verse verse verse 88!\&     
\end{astanza}
      \endnumbering
        \end{Leftside}
       \begin{Rightside}
            \beginnumbering
                \setstanzaindents{7,0}
                \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
                \linenummargin{left}
                \begin{astanza}[{\textbf{POEM3 ita}}] 
verse  verse verse 1!&  
verse verse verse 2!&
verse verse verse 3!&
verse verse verse 4!&   
verse verse verse 88!\&     
\end{astanza}
      \endnumbering
        \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Second schema:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}
% Additional Options

\begin{document}
        \large
            \begin{pages}
            \begin{Leftside}
                \beginnumbering
                    \setstanzaindents{7,0}
                    \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
               \begin{astanza}[{\textbf{POEM1 dial}}]
verse  verse verse 1!&  
verse verse verse 2!&   
verse verse verse 3!&   
verse  verse verse 1!&  
verse verse verse 2!&   
verse verse verse 3!&   
verse verse verse 88!\&             
    \end{astanza}
        \endnumbering
                    \beginnumbering
                    \setstanzaindents{7,0}
                    \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
    \begin{astanza}[{\textbf{POEM2 dial}}] 
verse  verse verse 1!&  
verse verse verse 2!&   
verse verse verse 3!&   
verse  verse verse 1!&  
verse verse verse 2!&   
verse verse verse 3!&   
verse verse verse 88!\&         
        \end{astanza}
            \endnumbering
                        \beginnumbering
                        \setstanzaindents{7,0}
                    \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
        \begin{astanza}[{\textbf{POEM3 dial}}]
verse  verse verse 1!&  
verse verse verse 2!&   
verse verse verse 3!&   
verse  verse verse 1!&  
verse verse verse 2!&   
verse verse verse 3!&   
verse verse verse 88!\&     
\end{astanza}
    \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
        \begin{Rightside}
            \beginnumbering
                \setstanzaindents{7,0}
                \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
                \linenummargin{left}
                \begin{astanza}[{\textbf{POEM1 ita}}] 
verse  verse verse 1!&  
verse verse verse 2!&   
verse verse verse 3!&
verse  verse verse 1!&  
verse verse verse 2!&   
verse verse verse 3!&   
verse verse verse 88!\&     
\end{astanza}
    \endnumbering
                \beginnumbering
                \setstanzaindents{7,0}
                    \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
      \begin{astanza}[{\textbf{POEM2 ita}}]
verse  verse verse 1!&  
verse verse verse 2!&
verse verse verse 3!&
verse  verse verse 1!&  
verse verse verse 2!&   
verse verse verse 3!&   
verse verse verse 88!\&     
\end{astanza}
    \endnumbering
                \beginnumbering
                \setstanzaindents{7,0}
                    \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
        \begin{astanza}[{\textbf{POEM3 ita}}] 
verse  verse verse 1!&  
verse verse verse 2!&   
verse verse verse 3!&   
verse  verse verse 1!&  
verse verse verse 2!&   
verse verse verse 3!&   
verse verse verse 88!\&     
\end{astanza}
      \endnumbering
        \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason things in parallel start on page 2 and not page 1 is because of how books are laid out. Odd numbers go on the 'recto' (right-hand side of an open book), while the even numbers are for the 'verso' (the back of the recto page, so on the left-hand side). Thus you can't have things in parallel starting on page 1 because it makes no sense to do so.